# Modify user form from password protected Add-In's

Tags: excel, vba, add-in, password-protection, userform

I'm trying to automate a process where I run a macro in an Excel Add-In. The Add-In macro requires user to populate a user form. The Excel Add-In is also password protected.

I know there's a way to write macros that populate user forms. I know that I first need the names of the form fields to modify them in the macro, BUT how do I get this information if the information is in a password protected Add-In?